# Connect Remote SAS server to an Oracle database on another remote server

Tags: oracle, sas

I have access to a remote Unix SAS server. I connect my local SAS to the remote server using ‘signon’ and ‘rsubmit’ . There is a separate remote server with an oracle database and I want to connect the remote SAS server to Oracle.

Do I go about creating a tnsnames.ora on the remote SAS server with login credentials and then declare a ‘libname’ using DSN?
I dont manage the remote SAS server, so this option  of creating tnsnames.ora is not easy. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual actually has an example where you spell out all of the information that would normally be placed in the TNSNAMES entry.

https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=acreldb&docsetTarget=p1qft7bzdij79zn1bxh59mc3w8xj.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en

> This next example connects to Oracle using the CONNECT_DATA=
>   descriptor.

```
libname x oracle user=myusr1 pw=mypwd1 
  path="(DESCRIPTION= 
          (ADDRESS_LIST=
            (ADDRESS= (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=pinkfloyd)(PORT=1521))
             )
              (CONNECT_DATA= 
       "         (SID=alien)
       "   )
       " )
       " ";
```

Your system admin will still have to make sure that SAS/Access to Oracle is install and drivers from Oracle are installed.

Comment: Thank you. The password has a special character (hash),  do I  need to do anything about it?

Comment: Add quotes. `pw='my#pass'`

Comment: Thanks. When I see: 'The ORACLE engine cannot be found.', it means the SAS Access to Oracle is not setup on the server?

Comment: Right. Run `proc setinit;run;` to see what SAS products are licensed.

Comment: Thanks, when i run it, I see: SAS/CONNECT. Can that be used for Oracle connection?

Comment: SAS/Connect is what you are using to connect SAS on one machine to SAS on another machine. Nothing to do with Oracle access.